# Numbering pages with hindi numerals using polyglossia

Tags: page-numbering, polyglossia, hindi

I use `Polyglossia` to produce multilingual documents, written in Arabic and English. I use the usual numeration with arabic numbers 1, 2, 3 and I want to number the pages by using the Hindi numbers, used in the arabic countries (see the MWE). How can I do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}  %% The option `numerals=mashriq` gives the hindi numeration
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}

\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

\raggedright\LR{Page 1

The arabic numbers, used in almost all the word: 1 2 3
}

\newpage

\LR{Page 2

The hindi numbers, used by the arabic people: \arabicdigits{1 2 3}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found in my old documents some thing like, from what I obtain the following commands, renumbering the pages with hindi digits:

```
%%%%        The Hindi counter is pagenumstyled
%\RequirePackage{arabicnumbers}
 \newcount\hindcnt
 \def\pagenumstyled{\afterassignment\dopagenumstyle\hindcnt}
 \def\dopagenumstyle{\arabicdigits{\number\hindcnt}}
 \renewcommand{\thepage}{\pagenumstyled\arabic{page}}
```